# Javascript Onkeydown loop till variable = false

Tags: javascript

Lets say var myVariable = true by default. Now how do i make it that on key press right arrow, this code is executed:

```
document.write("Right");
```

And will keep being executed till myVariable = false again...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jquery](https://api.jquery.com/keydown/) to do it easily:

```
    <script>$( "body" ).keydown(function( event ) {
  if ( event.which == 39) {
     event.preventDefault(); 

     document.write("Right");
  }
});</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind the event `keydown` to your `body` element.

```js
var myVariable = true
document.body.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (myVariable && e.keyCode === 39) {
    document.write("Right");
    myVariable = false;
    console.log('First time!');
  }
});
```

```html
<h1>Click here and then right arrow</h1>
```

Comment: You fixed it by changing `'keypress'` to `'keydown'`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is something like this:

```js
let arrowRight = null;

function keyChange(type, event) {
  if (type === 'down' && event.keyCode === 39) {
    if (!arrowRight) {
      arrowRight = setInterval(function() {
        document.body.append('right');
      }, 500);
    }
  }
  else if (type === 'up') {
    if (arrowRight) {
      clearInterval(arrowRight);
      arrowRight = null;
    }
  }
}

document.addEventListener('keyup', keyChange.bind(null, 'up'));
document.addEventListener('keydown', keyChange.bind(null, 'down'));
```

But since I'm adding listeners to document and `document.write` actually clear the document if the one you're writing on is already closed (loaded) you will have to use another method to write on your document (like `document.body.append`).

You can read more about `document.write` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write).